# Object serailizaton vs strings

Tags: java, sockets, serialization

I am working on my java assignment where I have to transfer different texts over the sockets. All the fields that I am transferring have specific meaning. So I created a string with a separator say '#'.(It is assumed that # does not appear in any field)

An example string would look like 'myName#mySurname#Address' etc.

There are currently 8 such fields. All these fields have same locations every time they are transferred. The receiving end parses this string and does the further calculation.

Now my question is is this approach good or creating a serializable class say Person with respective fields and then transferring this object over the network would be better?

I feel class is better as modification to the class is easier than a predefined string format but still I need expert opinion. Or is there a still better way to do it?

Comment: A better way to do it is to use a standard (usually text-based) format like JSON or XML. It has standard parsers already, so you don't need to parse it yourself. Serialized classes are slow and sensitive to changes.

Comment: A good discussion of this sort of thing is http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javaserial-1536170.html

Answer (score 1):

In production code Java serialization is usually avoided for being notoriously slow and verbose. Modern projects usually rely on (de)serialization libraries (such as [Cap'n Proto](https://capnproto.org/)) instead of baking their own.

However, the above concerns should not apply to your assignment. You will learn something important both by implementing your own format and by modeling this with Java objects and using standard Java serialization.